# MySQL ALTER Stament for Exchange Partition throws syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have followed the syntax for Exchange partition as given this doc : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.6-en/partitioning-management-exchange.html
But, it throws syntax error.

```
ALTER TABLE e EXCHANGE PARTITION p0 WITH TABLE e2
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'EXCHANGE PARTITION p0 WITH TABLE e2' at line 1

Could anyone tell how to correct this ?
Note: Table e, e2 are already created.
Mysql version: 5.2.40

Comment: the top of the referring page says: `In MySQL 5.6`, it is possible to exchange... so I guess 5.2 doesn't support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-management-exchange.html)

> In **MySQL 5.6**, it is possible to exchange a table partition or
>   subpartition with a table using ALTER TABLE pt EXCHANGE PARTITION p
>   WITH TABLE nt,

You are getting error cause it's not supported in `MySQL5.2` version. To check that, try changing the version `5.6` to `5.2` in the documentation URL[Magic Trick].

Comment: That's not true. Spec says `There are no rows in nt that lie outside the boundaries of the partition definition for p.`. Check the documentation link provided in answer for more info.

Comment: Thanks. So i understand data can be inserted with in boundary limits.. am i correct ?